# How to enable LocalStorage in Qt 5.3

Tags: qt, webkit, local-storage

I tried the method:

```
QWebSettings* settings = QWebSettings::globalSettings();
settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalStorageEnabled, true);
auto path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::GenericDataLocation);
settings->setOfflineStoragePath(path);
```

`window.localStorage` is `true` (not `null` or `undefined`), but when I insert an item into the localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem("b","isaac");
alert(localStorage["b"]);
```

The error happens, and the error messages in the webkit inspector console are:

> QuotaExceededError: DOM Exception 22: An attempt was made to add something to storage that exceeded the quota.

Answer (score 6):

I was raging all day, because it was not working after restart of the app.
So I think this will be helpfull for someone:

```
QWebSettings* settings = QWebSettings::globalSettings();
settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalStorageEnabled, true);
auto path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::GenericDataLocation);
settings->setOfflineStoragePath(path);
settings->enablePersistentStorage(path);
```

Notice the enablePersistentStorage

Answer (score 3):

I forgot that I've enabled a very important switch:

```
settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PrivateBrowsingEnabled,true);
```

This will set the browser to private mode and prevent you to insert values to localStorage. But the official api doc doesn't mention it.

You just need to disable the switcher so you can solve the problem:

```
settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PrivateBrowsingEnabled,false);
```